# Is there a way to make instructions with 300ms between them?

Tags: android, kotlin, native, delay, vibration

I have this problem: I should vibrate the phone for 500ms *, 300ms of pause, 500ms * of vibration, 300ms of pause and finally 500ms * of vibration. I tried using Handler but unfortunately it's like they add up in one wait time. Is there a specific way to do all these operations sequentially and by putting a delay between them? A thousand thanks.

Time varies depending on many factors

```
    val vibration = requireActivity().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
        vibration.vibrate(code.code.duration1.toLong())
    }, 600)
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
        vibration.vibrate(code.code.duration2.toLong())
    }, 2000)
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
        vibration.vibrate(code.code.duration3.toLong())
        id.setImageDrawable(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(requireActivity(), R.drawable.ic_play))
    }, 3600)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code, which is working for me perfectly.

```
fun Fragment.vibratePhone() {
    val vibrator = context?.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            vibrator.vibrate(
                VibrationEffect.createPredefined(VibrationEffect.EFFECT_CLICK),
                AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                    .setHapticChannelsMuted(false)
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
                    .build()
            )
        } else {
            vibrator.vibrate(
                VibrationEffect.createOneShot(VIBRATION_TIME, VIBRATION_AMPLITUDE),
                AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
                    .build()
            )
        }
    } else {
        vibrator.vibrate(longArrayOf(0, 100, 50, 100, 50, 100), -1)
    }
}
```

In the above code, you will see that,

- 0 means delay
- 100 means vibrate for 100ms
- 50 means delay
- 100 means vibrate for 100ms and so on.
- Repetition: at last -1 means vibration will happen in the pattern you have defined and won't repeat else define several times you want to repeat it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Handlers or Threads, you can use a coroutine which would be more readable.

```kotlin
myScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
    vibration.vibrate(500)
    delay(500 + 300)
    vibration.vibrate(500)
    delay(500 + 300)
    vibration.vibrate(500)
}
```